# Connection Abondoned Error in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

When I am trying to insert/update in postgresql from the app, I am getting the following error. Search/Select works fine.
If I log into postgresql, I am able to update/insert from the pgadmin/pgstudio.
I am using Spring-boot app to connect to Postgresql

```
2016-12-21T14:42:30.66-0600 [App/0]      OUT 2016-12-21 20:42:30.665  INFO 29 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT 2016-12-21 20:42:45.412  WARN 29 --- [:1482352635282]] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Connection has been abandoned PooledConnection[org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2895a495]:java.lang.Exception
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getThreadDump(ConnectionPool.java:1081)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:789)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:187)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1929)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:118)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:82)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.findByUserName(Unknown Source)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at com.ge.power.brs.managers.impl.EventManager.saveEvent(EventManager.java:206)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at com.ge.power.brs.managers.ComponentManager.retrieveComponents(ComponentManager.java:33)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at com.ge.power.brs.managers.impl.AuthorityManager.retrieveAuthorities(AuthorityManager.java:34)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at com.ge.power.brs.controllers.EventControllerV1.insertEvent(EventControllerV1.java:146)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.41-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:677)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
2016-12-21T14:42:45.42-0600 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-12-21T14:43:02.13-0600 [RTR/2]      OUT brs-dev-brs-connector-asset-workflow.run.asv-pr.ice.predix.io - [21/12/2016:20:43:02.119 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 0 68 "-" "Java/1.8.0_101" 10.128.38.9:61568 x_forwarded_for:"65.216.161.209" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:4eebb4cb-e508-4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issue with the other spring-boot application which was causing the problem